# cbind dataframe in R with placeholders

Tags: r, wildcard, placeholder, cbind

Imagine I have three dataframes:

```
data.frame1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:10))
data.frame2 <- data.frame(x=c(11:20))
data.frame3 <- data.frame(x=c(21:30))
```

I could bind them together by explicitely naming each of them:

```
res.data.frame <- cbind(data.frame1, data.frame2, data.frame3)
```

However, I am looking for more dynamic ways to do so, e.g. with placeholders.

This saves somehow the three dataframes in a new dataframe, but not in a usable format:

```
res.data.frame1 <- as.data.frame(mapply(get, grep("^data.frame.$", ls(), value=T)))
```

[image]

This command would only save the three names:

```
res.data.frame2 <- grep(pattern = "^data.frame.$", ls(), value=T)
```

This one only gives an error message:

```
res.data.frame3  <- do.call(cbind, lapply(ls(pattern = "^data.frame.$")), get)
```

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Comment: You could use `mget` i.e. `do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern="data\\.frame\\d+")))`

Comment: Also `do.call(cbind, sapply(ls(pattern = "^data.frame.$"), get))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

Assuming `ls()`

```
# [1] "data.frame1" "data.frame2" "data.frame3"

as.data.frame(Reduce("cbind", sapply(ls(), function(i) get(i))))
```

Based on @akrun's comment, this can be simplified to

```
as.data.frame(Reduce("cbind", mget(ls())))
```

Comment: Usually, `do.call` tends to be faster than `Reduce` but of course context-dependent! Also, `sapply(ls()...` can be replaced with our ignored apply famly sibling: `eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(i) i)`!

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the comment. I prefer the `do.call` but I only tried it after seeing akrun's comment. Since akrun's comment already mentions it, I thought I wouldn't update my answer to use it as well. I never knew about `eapply`, so thanks for the mention. In this case, I think `mget` is appropriate, although this also came from akrun.